# Adjusting nested pie chart in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
sales_gender = current_employees.groupby("gender")['amount'].mean()

male_college = current_employees.loc[(current_employees['gender'] == 0)]

female_college = current_employees.loc[(current_employees['gender'] == 1)]

male_college = male_college.groupby("college")["gender"].count()

male_college = male_college.tolist()

female_college = female_college.groupby("college")["gender"].count()
female_college = female_college.tolist()

gender_college = male_college + female_college
gender_college

gender = ["Male","Female"]

gender_college_label = [ "Male Degree","Female No Degree", "Female Degree","Male No Degree",]

plt.figure(1)
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

size = 0.3
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 9.0
cmap = plt.colormaps["tab20c"]
outer_colors = cmap(np.arange(3)*4)
inner_colors = cmap([1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10])

plt.pie(sales_gender, radius=1, colors=outer_colors, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'), 
    labels=gender, autopct='%1.1f%%', pctdistance=(1-size/2), textprops={'fontsize': 12})

plt.pie(gender_college, radius=1-size, colors=inner_colors, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'), 
    labels=gender_college, labeldistance=0.7, pctdistance=(1-size/2), textprops={'fontsize': 12})

plt.title('Sales Performance by Gender & Number of Gender with degrees or not',fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')

plt.legend(handles[1:], gender_college_label, loc=(0.9, 0.1))

plt.show()
```

this is my code to create a nested pie chart using matplotlib and the image is the output

[image]

I want both pie chart to be inline with each other so example 36 and 9 would fit perfectly within the orange 49.6% female and 33 and 8 would fit perfectly within the 50.4% Male

is this possible without using any other libraries and keeping the solution as simple as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify the wedges directly. Given the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3
vals = [60, 40]
vals2 = [70, 30]


cmap = plt.colormaps["tab20c"]
outer_colors = cmap(np.arange(3) * 4)
inner_colors = cmap([1, 10])

ax.pie(
    vals,
    radius=1,
    colors=outer_colors,
    wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor="w"),
)

ax.pie(
    vals2,
    radius=1 - size,
    colors=inner_colors,
    wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor="w"),
)

ax.set(aspect="equal")
plt.show()
```

Produces this:

[image]

So you need to get the patches like so and setting their theta values based on the outside values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3
vals = [60, 40]
vals2 = [70, 30]


cmap = plt.colormaps["tab20c"]
outer_colors = cmap(np.arange(3) * 4)
inner_colors = cmap([1, 10])

ax.pie(
    vals,
    radius=1,
    colors=outer_colors,
    wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor="w"),
)

wedges, *_ = ax.pie(
    vals2,
    radius=1 - size,
    colors=inner_colors,
    wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor="w"),
)
wedges[0].set_theta2((vals[0] / 100) * 360)
wedges[1].set_theta1((vals[0] / 100) * 360)

ax.set(aspect="equal")
plt.show()
```

Which gives:
[image]